# Django Cassandra pagination

Tags: django, cassandra, django-rest-framework, cql, cqlengine

How can we paginate the Django Rest API with Cassandra, there is no offset to paginate, the only solution preferred so far is to use greater than(>) or less than(<) on primary keys with the limit.

[This](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/pagination-with-cassandra-and-what-we-can-learn-from-it/) will work to an extent, but only if I know the last or first item of the current page,

- What if I need to move from 1st page to 7th page directly?
- What if my starting index gets deleted in another user session?